# Flutter google map market handler

Tags: flutter, google-maps, google-maps-markers

How can I get marker information while clicking marker on flutter google map? example marker id.
How can I get marker id or other marker information?

When I search this question I got reposes on how to get latitude and longitude on google map onTap event, but this is not enough information my requirement.

Comment: You can create your custom marker and you can show whatever you want when you click marker

Comment: Thank you Rohan Jariwala for your response.
 Can you help me create custom marker and get information about the marker?